# Music controls with HTML and JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html, audio

I have (many) images on my web page, and each plays a song when clicked.  Later, I plan to play a random song with each image click, as each picture is an album cover.  The code for each image looks a bit like this:

```
<a onclick="PlaySoundM4A('money');">
    <img class="mySlidesTwo fading" src="dark2.jpeg" style="height:21vh;width:21vh;max-width: 200px;max-height: 200px;">
</a>
```

And here is my JS function:

```
function PlaySoundM4A(fileName) {

    var mFour = new Audio(fileName + ".m4a");
    mFour.play();
}
```

I'd like to know how to have a menu (or at least a few buttons) that allow a user to pause, mute, or end the track.  The issue is that the song is a variable set within this function.  How do I reference it in another function (like a stop function)?

Answer (score 1):

What if you make it a global variable

```
var mFour;
function PlaySoundM4A(fileName) {
    mFour = new Audio(fileName + ".m4a");
    mFour.play();
}

function StopSound(){
    mFour.stop();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

use the `audio` tag. See https://www.w3schools.com/html/html5_audio.asp for more information. Your script only has to set the `display` of the `audio` tag to `show`. The user can then control it by themselves, and you can similate this input to stop and start the audio.

Comment: I tried to do that, but I don't know how to incorporate that into an onclick function for an image.

Comment: you can simply say in the onclick of the image `document.getElementById("yourmusic'sid").style.display="show"` @TfarcrawIIV

Comment: Okay, but I need the audio file within the player to vary.  How can I do that?

Comment: create an array and randomly select an index from it then do different things depending on the value of the item in that index. The array can contain anything you want. @TfarcrawIIV

Comment: In my answer, you would change the id depeding on the resulting value. You would create several file players, then choose one depending on the result of the array. @TfarcrawIIV

Answer (score 0):

The simplest way would be to create a variable outside your function (maybe on the global scope) that would store the song:

```
var myFour;

function PlaySoundM4A(fileName) {

    mFour = new Audio(fileName + ".m4a");
    mFour.play();
}

function stopFunction(){
    if(!myFour){ return; }

    //do the stop thing
}
```